# Can multiple checkout be enabled just in one branch in tfs 2013?

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS2013 and we have need to have main branch on server workspace with disabled multiple checkouts, and to have another branch again on server workspace but with enabled multiple checkouts. Is this possible in any other way than using local workspace on that second branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The settings for checkout are at a team project level. However, there's no good reason to have exclusive checkouts enabled in the first place -- they are a terrible detriment to productivity. If two developers change the same file, they'll have to merge the files. It's not a big deal.

Comment: I've seen some nasty merges and overwriting of the code done by other people. Exclusive checkout is great feature for preventing that.